# Why isn’t ace2 included in SARS‑CoV‑2 PPI map?

Tags: proteins, covid-19, sars-cov-2, protein-protein-interaction

I'm doing my master's thesis on drug repositioning for SARS‑CoV‑2 using AI more specifically network medicine,

I found only one human protein-protein interactions (PPIs) map from [Gordon et al.](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2020/03/27/2020.03.22.002386)

The manuscript doesn't include the ace2 protein which the SARS‑CoV‑2 spike protein directly binds with. AVE2 is a host cell surface receptor facilitating virus entry and thereafter replication.

Thus, I'm looking for PPI map that includes ACE2 protein but i can't find any

Secondly, is there a reason why it's not been included ?

PS: I have very basic knowledge of this domain

Comment: In fairness to the authors they do included it, viz. "captopril  modulates  ACE2  indirectly  via  its  direct  interaction  with  Angiotensin Converting  Enzyme,  ACE". So they hold results on ACE and therein have a claim for ACE2